# Как вы запоминаете побуквенное правописание слов | How do you remember the letter by letter spelling of words

Tags: правописание

Русский использует другой алфавит, чем я, так что если я хочу знать написание *привет*, например, правописание этого слова, а не произношение на английском, что я должен делать?

Translation: Russian uses a different alphabet than I do, so if I want to know the spelling of привеt for example, the letter to letter writing of it rather than the pronunciation in English, what should I do? .

Comment: Actually, Russian spelling is quite phonetic, you just write what you hear and observe some spelling formalities, like the reduced vowels or ь at the end of the present tense 2nd person singular verbs. Nothing special.

Comment: How can you prionounce привет in English?

Comment: You pronounce the Russian "hi" like priviyet

Comment: I was talking about words like the formal hello "Hello" where there are so many letters it is hard for me to write it phonetically, I am an English native :)

Comment: Yours "thought" will be phonetically spelled in Russian as "тооф", imagine, how hard it to know the spelling too   :) Russian the language hasn't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)

Comment: For me reading texts is the best way - it happens naturally, I even don't try to remember the spelling, misspellings just start to look wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Русская орфография основывается на морфологическом принципе. Если вы хотите грамотно писать на русском языке, то надо выучить основные морфемы из которых образуются русские слова. Например, слово "cделать" произносится как [zd'el٨t'], но зная, что есть приставка "с-" и суффиксы "-а" и "-ть" пишем именно так. В целом русская графика гораздо ближе к произношению, чем та же английская. Есть несколько несложных законов редукции и ассимиляции, плюс сравнительно небольшое количество слов с историческим написанием, в остальном же написание соответствует произношению.
Во взятом вами слове "привет" можно допустить две ошибки: "пр(и/е)ве(т/д). Согласная на конце слова проявляется если слово просклонять "с приве**т**ом", здесь "т" уже в сильной позиции перед гласной, значит и в слабой позиции пишем "т". Гласные звуки проверяются ударением, но в данном случае это невозможно, значит, нужно запомнить, или свериться со словарём.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84574/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR:

1. Use a spellchecker, which is very simple, use an orthographic dictionary.
2. If you learn, try writing dictations.
3. Remember the written form, decompose the word into phonemes and distinct them (see an example below)

Written Russian language keeps the writing of words above pronunciation and mostly keeps the written forms the same across transformations. There are several reasons: a) vowel reduction made every minor dialect have different pronunciation of the same vowel, b) written Russian came not from Russian, but from Church Slavonic. I assume that the scholars tried to keep the sacred texts unchanged. Later it became a written tradition and a common denominator for dialects.

The way functionally literate native Russians do is remember the graphical image of a word. Plus we have in mind its sources, like the base and the prefixes/suffixes. E.g. `прибрежный` = `при-` (at) `-брег-` (shore) `-н-` (adjective suffix) `-ый` (masculine adjective termination). Now, `при-` is similar to `пре-` and often both pronounced with `и`, but we know that `пре-` means "over" and not suitable here.

Of course there are false friends like similar words that have different vowels in them, that natives confuse for related and use to check one another, like шп**а**ргалка/шп**о**ра. But that's part of the deal.